# Unity 3d: how can I display an animation on my character by clicking on a button from my UI designed on UI toolkit?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I have this UI designed on UI Toolkit in Unity 3D. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Geh1T.png)

I want my character to do a different animation when I click each of the buttons on the UI. I have already set an animator with the needed clips and a boolean var called "deporteAn". Also, I have my UIController script where I initialized all of the buttons with their UI names and then I call a method that does the action when the buttons are clicked. As it is shown on this code:

```
public class UIController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button deporteButton;
    public Button lecturaButton;
    public Button trabajoButton;
    public Button vacunacionButton;
    public Button gatoButton;
    public Button perroButton;
    public Button ratonButton;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        deporteButton = rootVisualElement.Q<Button>("deporte-button");
        lecturaButton = rootVisualElement.Q<Button>("lectura-button");
        trabajoButton = rootVisualElement.Q<Button>("trabajo-button");
        vacunacionButton = rootVisualElement.Q<Button>("vacunacion-button");

        gatoButton = rootVisualElement.Q<Button>("gato-button");
        perroButton = rootVisualElement.Q<Button>("perro-button");
        ratonButton = rootVisualElement.Q<Button>("raton-button");


        deporteButton.clicked += DeporteButton_clicked;//calling the method when deporteButton is clicked.

        public void DeporteButton_clicked()//Method where the animation should be displayed.
        {
            //Shows the animation on my character.
            animator.SetBool("deporteAn", true);
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Deporte clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem might be that this script is attached to the UIDocument. I've tried to attached it to the character gameobject but it didn't work. I have thought that maybe creating another script, attach it to the character gameobject and call the method there could work so I did this:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour

{
   
    public UIController uiButton;

    public void Start()
    {
        AnimationButtons();
    }
    public void AnimationButtons()
    {
        uiButton = GetComponent<UIController>();

        if (uiButton)
        {
            uiButton.deporteButton.clicked += uiButton.DeporteButton_clicked;
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Button pressed");
        }
        else
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Button not pressed");
        }
    }

}
```

But it only shows "Button not pressed" and do nothing on the game view. What can I do? Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head uiButton variable is null so always "Button not pressed" will be written

look @ this code in my pic I think same error occurs at your code

[image]

So check if **UIController** , **PlayerController**  attached to the same game object